# On page refresh, destructuring props gives unhydrated values in componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a strange error in my application that I haven't come across in React.

Basically, when the page refreshes, I grab certain parameters from the URL, make API requests on the queries and then populate my Redux state with the results.

For example:

```
 async componentDidMount() {
    const {
      values1, values2, match,
    } = this.props;

    await getSingleData(match.params.id);
    await getData(values1, values2);
  }
```

So from the URL parameter, I grab the Id, then make an API request to get the data and store it in Redux. However, when I use the desctructured syntax, I get empty or null values. When using the destructured syntax, it seems like it references the empty Redux store before the data hydration, while the full reference gives the correct values after the data hydration.

When I use the full `this.props.values1` and `this.props.values2` reference, it works fine.

For example, this code, everything works like it's supposed to:

```
 async componentDidMount() {
    const {
      values1, values2, match,
    } = this.props;

    await getSingleData(match.params.id);
    await getData(this.props.values1, this.props.values2);
  }
```

I'm confused as to why this is happening. As far as I understand, descructuring objects will have the same reference as the non-descructured counterpart. But it's not the case apparently. Any input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Destructuring happens immediately when the function is called and at that time, this.props is null.

After call to `await getSingleData(match.params.id)` (which is run after the destructuring) `this.props` is filled.

Therefore, you are able to access `this.props.value1`.

Destructuring does not track or observe the original object's changes.

Comment: That makes sense. So ideally, destructuring should happen after the first API call then?

Comment: so is destructuring making a copy of the object instead of reference? if it's a reference, shouldn't the changes be present in the destructuring object as well?